# Do I need to use a before "few" in this case and why? or why not?

Tags: grammar

I always do a grammar mistake with `a`. I would like to improve my understanding for a special case of using `a`. For example,

*Most values are 0 or very close to 0, while a few of them are -1*.

Here, I think I do not need to use `a` before few. However, I do not know why?

Could you help, me please?

Comment: Perhaps this will help - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Most values are 0 or very close to 0, while **a** few of them are -1.

`A` before `few` should be better in the sentence above. There are still some values which are -1, aren't there? So, to emphasize the fact that there **are** such values, we need to use `a`. More examples:

> Most of my friends are students but **a** few of them are not. (some of my friends are actually not students)
>
> I have few friends. (not using `a` I emphasize the fact that I have almost no friends - their number is **insufficient**, I feel lonely and unhappy)